# Swift 3.0 Optional Chaining

Tags: swift

I am new to swift so this is definitely a newbie level question. I was pondering on some Swift 3.0 documentation where I noticed a potential error. I am wondering if the example is incorrect (or ambiguous) or I am in fact missing out on some guideline.

See http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/Optional/ the section about Optional Chaining.

> **OPTIONAL CHAINING**
>
> To safely access the properties and methods of a wrapped instance, use the postfix optional chaining operator (`?`). The following example uses optional chaining to access the `hasSuffix(_:)` method on a `String?` instance.
>
> ```
> if let isPNG = imagePaths["star"]?.hasSuffix(".png") {
>     print("The star image is in PNG format")
> }
> // Prints "The star image is in PNG format"
> ```

AFAIU, `imagePaths["star"]?.hasSuffix(".png")` is only supposed to safely unwrap `imagePaths` and run `hasSuffix()` only if `imagePaths["star"]` results in `Optional.some(wrapped)`. This implies that `isPNG` will be either `true` or `false`. Therefore, the implication of the above sample is incorrect where it implicitly claims that if this safely unwraps, then the value is always true.

Here are some examples to explain what I am talking about:

```
if let isPNG = imagePaths["star"]?.hasSuffix(".png") {
    print("The star has png format")
} else {
    print("The star does not have png format")
}

if let isPNG = imagePaths["portrait"]?.hasSuffix(".png") {
    print("The portrait has png format")
} else {
    print("The portrait does not have png format")
}
// "The portrait has png format\n"

if let isPNG = imagePaths["alpha"]?.hasSuffix(".png") {
    print("The alpha has png format")
} else {
    print("The alpha does not have png format")
}
// "The alpha does not have png format\n"
```

I am simply wondering if my current analysis is wrong or if SwiftDoc.org needs to change this particular example.

Comment: I agree. The documentation is incorrect. The correct version of there example would be `if let isPNG = imagePaths["star"]?.hasSuffix(".png") where isPNG { ... }` or `if imagePaths["star"]?.hasSuffix(".png") == true { ... }`. But their example is incorrect.

Comment: ... or perhaps more descriptive: `if let img = imagePaths["star"] where img.hasSuffix(".png") { ... }`.

Comment: That example actually originates from Apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional (generated from https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift), so someone should file a bug report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your analysis is correct, and the example at SwiftDoc.org is at least
misleading, as the following code demonstrates:

```
let imagePaths = ["star": "image1.tiff"]

if let isPNG = imagePaths["star"]?.hasSuffix(".png") {
    print("The star has png format")
} else {
    print("The star does not have png format")
}

// Output: The star has png format
```

The optional binding succeeds if

```
imagePaths["star"]?.hasSuffix(".png")
```

is not `nil`, and that is if the optional chaining could be executed,
i.e. if `imagePaths["star"] != nil`.

A correct way to test for all situations would be

```
if let isPNG = imagePaths["star"]?.hasSuffix(".png") {
    if isPNG {
        print("The star has png format")
    } else {
        print("The star does not have png format")
    }
} else {
    print("No path in dictionary")
}
```

Of course this can be simplified in various ways (nil-coalescing operators, pattern matching, ...). For example

```
switch(imagePaths["star"]?.hasSuffix(".png")) {
case true?:
    print("The star has png format")
case false?:
    print("The star does not have png format")
case nil:
    print("No path in dictionary")
}
```

or

```
let isPNG = imagePaths["star"]?.hasSuffix(".png") ?? false
```

(More examples in the comments to the question.)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. The final code is what I came up with at the end. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you are conflating Optionals with Bool. They are not the same, although in some circumstances nil acts like false.

Comment: I interpreted the example from the `SwiftDoc.org` and tried to create other examples as I posted above. I have this much confidence that the examples that I created are valid. So it looks like its an issue with the original example itself and what it's trying to imply.